# File-Upload in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: php, upload, typo3-6.2.x

When trying to upload a file via fileadmin I get the following PHP error:

[Wed Nov 12 14:19:21 2014] [error][client 80.109.35.163] File does not exist: /home/develop/www/www2.server124.at/**typo3/typo3**, referer: http://www2.server124.at/typo3/mod.php?M=file_list&moduleToken=9f16e6413517ce78cb33f0ed4cf94a2f49449546&id=1%3A%2F_migrated%2F

Apparently the modul is points to the wrong directory. After creating "typo3" underneath the "typo3" directory the CMS complains about the missing /home/develop/www/www2.server124.at/**typo3/typo3/sysext** directory.

Everything works fine in my local Windows environment but not on the Linux destination server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was caused by an "open_basedir" restriction.